# Installing Onesignal Cocoapod

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, onesignal

First I have firebase pods ( core-auth-storage-firestore ) and everything is fine, when I installed Onesignal pod I got this (error1):

[Image: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CGRectZero", referenced from:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb0EI.jpg)

If I delete 'Onesignal' or delete 'FirebaseAuth' then no error happen and the build runs successfully. I can't use both OneSignal and FirebaseAuth right now.

How can I fix it? I want to install both 'OneSignal' and 'FirebaseAuth'.

Here is my Podfile:
[My Podfile Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPLvh.png)

I hace tried but no good results,

- Podfile without 'Firebase/Auth' was built successfully:

[Image: Podfile Without 'Firebase/Auth'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cuwg.png)

- Podfile without 'OneSignal' was built successfully:

[Image: Podfile without 'OneSignal'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyZP7.png)

but if Both it will be error: 1- Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CGRectZero", referenced from: -[FIRAuthWebView createWebView] in FirebaseAuth. 2- ( Linker Command failed with exit code 1 )

I can either choose FirebaseAuth or onesignal to install to my project and build it successfully.I don't know why I can't build with both.

Comment: There is an extra issue after Installing 'OneSignal'. I see that all of frameworks have a (build setting option) named : 'Require Only App-Extension-Safe API' has changed to yes. then I got an error with 'ARSLineProgress' pod.           /n  Error: ('shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.) I don't understand why these errors happen

Comment: You should run a pod update in order to get the latest version of our SDK (currently 2.1.16 as you can) i found this answer from this link https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/96

Comment: you made mistake in pod file you write **target name UpdateNotification** this is wrong. Your target is your project name. please change that and try again

Comment: Also check setup guide on this link https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

Comment: I have followed setup guid. The are 2 targets (project target and notification target).

Comment: the version that you are talking about (2.1.15) I think it is old. (Currently 2.6.2 in the guid)

Comment: No, i install latest version  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0', i don't know about notification target. Try to search issue in OneSignal issues list, may be you can get some solution from that.

Comment: I can either choose FirebaseAuth or onesignal to install to my project.I don't know why I can't install both

Comment: Let me try to install both and check issue come or not.

Comment: every time I try to install together I got these errors: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CGRectZero", referenced from: -[FIRAuthWebView createWebView] in FirebaseAuth. ---------------------------------------------------------------  ( Linker Command failed with exit code 1 )

Comment: **i am not getting any error i use below pod file and install it and run code** 
platform :ios, '10.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'CaplarMap' do
pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end